# i am able to get the the text results how can i push them into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am able to get all the contact numbers,but result is coming in text format(`8045318762`,`9632427326`).

How can I store them into `array` like `["9632427326","8045318762"]`.
I mean similar to push.

My DOM is:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;" class="number">
  <span id="mob0">0
 </span>8045318762      
 <script type="text/javascript"> whichVer('ver0'); </script>
</span>
<span style="font-weight:bold;" class="number">
  <span id="mob1">1
 </span>9632427326  
 <script type="text/javascript"> whichVer('ver1'); </script>
</span>

**I am using something like this:**
```

which returns only text i want array(similar to push).

```
alert($('.number').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text());
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` and return array of numbers.

```js
var data = $('.number').contents().map(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.trim() != '') return Number(this.textContent);
}).get();

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-weight:bold;" class="number">
  <span id="mob0">0
 </span>8045318762
</span>
<span style="font-weight:bold;" class="number">
  <span id="mob1">1
 </span>9632427326
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to filter out the mobile no text. 
like this :

> ```
>   function getMobArr(){
>     var arr=[];
>     $.each($(".number"),function(index,value){
>         //filter text with regex for mobile 10 digit no.
>         var match=$(value).text().match(/([\d]{10})/i);
>         arr.push(match[1]);
>     })
>     return arr;
> }
> ```

**output:**

["8045318762", "9632427326"]